# Picture is not posted on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

hey I'm using this code technique to post on my fb wall

```
    //      parameters.putString("description", "Muslim Baby Names");
            parameters.putString("picture","http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/4834/pic1qu.png");
```

it does make a post but picture odes not get posted.

Kindly tell me how should I do it

Comment: Have you tried this with another picture (from another domain)? You are using an imageshack picture URL – but these image hosters can be quite picky sometimes when it comes to whom they actually show the images. It might be that imageshack sees the Facebook scraper as “just another bot”, and therefore refuses to deliver the actual image. Using “See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL” in the debug tool just gives the message “Document returned no data” – https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fimg208.imageshack.us%2Fimg208%2F4834%2Fpic1qu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out our example app that uses the Android SDK, Hackbook.  [Here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/Hackbook.java#L290) is the relevant code that uploads a photo to a user's wall from a remote URL.

For your example, this is how you would do it:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("url", "http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/4834/pic1qu.png");
params.putString("caption", "Muslim Baby Names");
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST");
```

Let me know if that helps!